# How to avoid duplication of components using React-Navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I had **5 screens** with the same styles and layout, but some text and button logic difference. 
 I tried to keep everything in **one component**, passing there the name of the component I need to mimic, but it grew up in **nested if/else** all around, what made the code very intricate. 
 What is lesser of these two evils and what should I do: **duplicate** the components in favor of simplicity or keep them in **one place** and lose the readability?

Here's the "all in one" component

```
const Pin = props => {
  const {
    navigation: { navigate, getParam },
    loading,
    savePin,
    signIn,
    toggleModal,
  } = props

  const [pin, setPin] = useState('')
  const isInSignInStack = getParam('isInSignInStack') ? 'isInSignInStack' : false
  const isConfirmPinSignUp = getParam('isConfirmPinSignUp') ? 'isConfirmPinSignUp' : false
  const isChangePin = getParam('isChangePin') ? 'isChangePin' : false
  const isEnterNewPin = getParam('isEnterNewPin') ? 'isEnterNewPin' : false
  const isConfirmNewPin = getParam('isConfirmNewPin') ? 'isConfirmNewPin' : false
  const newPin = getParam('newPin')

  const handleSavePin = () => savePin(pin).then(() => navigate('ConfirmPinSignUp'))

  const navigateHome = () => navigate('Home')

  const handleAuthenticate = () =>
    compose(
      then(navigateHome),
      then(signIn),
      savePin
    )(pin)

  const validatePin = () =>
      isConfirmNewPin
        ? equals(newPin, pin)
          ? savePin(pin).then(() => navigate('SuccessPinChange'))
          : toggleModal('pin isn't match')
        : getPin().then(({ password }) =>
            equals(password, pin)
              ? navigate(isChangePin ? 'ConfirmNewPin' : 'Success', { ...(isChangePin ? { newPin: pin } : {}) })
              : toggleModal('pin isn't match')
      )

  const textObj = {
    isInSignInStack: 'Enter your pin',
    isConfirmPinSignUp: 'Enter your pin once again',
    isChangePin: 'Enter your old pin',
    isEnterNewPin: 'Enter the new pin',
    isConfirmNewPin: 'Enter the new pin once again',
  }

  return (
    <Container style={styles.container}>
      <Content scrollEnabled={false} contentContainerStyle={styles.content}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>
          {pathOr(
            'Come up with the new pin',
            isInSignInStack || isConfirmPinSignUp || isChangePin || isEnterNewPin || isConfirmNewPin,
            textObj
          )}
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <CodeInput />
        </View>
        {isConfirmPinSignUp || (
          <View style={styles.aknowledgementView}>
            {isInSignInStack
               ? <Text style={styles.text} onPress={handleForgotPassword}>
                   FORGOT PIN
                 </Text>
               : isEnterNewPin && (
                <>
                  <Text style={styles.greenText}>Attention! Don't use your old pin</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.greenText}>codes or passwords, come up with the new one</Text>
                </>
              )}
          </View>
        )}
        <Button
          style={isEmpty(pin) ? styles.btnDisabled : styles.btn}
          onPress={() =>
              isInSignInStack
                ? handleAuthenticate
                : anyTrue(isConfirmPinSignUp, isChangePin) ? validatePin : handleSavePin
          }
          disabled={anyTrue(isEmpty(pin), loading)}
        >
          {loading ? <Spinner color="black" /> : <Text style={styles.btnText}>Next</Text>}
        </Button>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  )
}

Pin.navigationOptions = ({ navigation: { getParam } }) => {
  const isInSignInStack = getParam('isInSignInStack')
  const isChangePin = getParam('isChangePin')
  const isEnterNewPin = getParam('isEnterNewPin')

  return {
    title: isInSignInStack ? 'SignIn' : anyTrue(isChangePin, isEnterNewPin) ? 'Change PIN' : 'Register'
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  //
})

Pin.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.shape({
    navigate: PropTypes.func,
    getParam: PropTypes.func,
  }).isRequired,
  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  savePin: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  toggleModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  signIn: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = compose(
  pick(['loading']),
  path(['user'])
)

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  savePin,
  signIn,
  toggleModal,
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Pin)
```

Comment: This is highly dependent on _what_ is being duplicated across your components

Comment: Checkout the Factory Pattern. Perhaps, its what you are searching for.

Comment: @tic Hi! Everything is identical, but the text and the logic that the button is handling is different

Comment: "some text and button logic difference" These should be passed in as props for the text to display and the click handlers for the buttons.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Hi! How does it solve the need to distinguish between what data to pass in as props? I still need if/else for this. Can you please check out the code I pinned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you should not couple the components which belong to different use cases as they will change for a different reasons and at different times, even though they look identically now they will change later. Don't write the "super component" that cover all the use cases, because it will become a mess very quickly

Answer (score 3):

Make a generic button component that takes a click handler and text as a prop then simply pass the values as props:

for instance if you have some button component like:

```
export const Button = ({ children, handler }) =>
  <button onPress={handler}>
    {children}
  </button>;
```

Then you could use it like

```
<Button handler={this.yourClickHandler} >{"Some Text"}</Button>
```

Comment: @Jake Thank you! But it doesn't solve the need in if/else. It will truly make the code a little more concise but won't change it too much

Comment: @Makar Can you explain what the ternary statement is being used for? It seems it being used for routing. If this is the case it shouldn't be handled inside the button component

Comment: @Jake Depending on the route I'm in, the ternary handles what action should be dispatched: authenticate and then navigate to "Home" screen or validate/save pin and navigate to "Success" screen. Can you explain why button shouldn't handle navigation and do you think that the navigation logic is the root of my problem?

Comment: @Makar it seems you need to step back one component. By that I mean your main component for each screen should have the click handler defined in it and if its using this Pin component then that handler will be passed to it and then passed down to the button.

Comment: @Makar so for instance if you are in the login screen you will pass this Pin component the handleAuthenticate function as a prop and then the pass that prop to to the button. Therefore whatever handler you pass the Pin component, that will be set as the button logic

Comment: @Jake You have a point, but the Pin component doesn't have a parent, because Pin is just a screen where I navigate to after previous screen and so on. I'm using the stack navigation from **react-navigation** library and the only entry point I have is **createStackNavigator**, but I can't connect it to the redux and pass props or actions to the screens from there - only parameters with names or smth. Although I can pass props from the connected components, from which I navigate to the Pin, but should they know about my Pin's button behavior? e.g. if I navigate from the "Home" screen to "Pin"?